# How to detect 404 errors from express.static

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `express.static` to serve static files, as below:

```
['/images','/packages','/scripts','/stylesheets'].forEach(p => {
  app.use(p, express.static(siteSettings.publicFolder + p));
});
```

This is working great, however when a file that doesn't exist is requested, express will raise the error as expected but this is hitting my custom error catch-all route:

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'production' ? {} : err;

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('views/error');
});
```

This is meaning that file 404 errors (for example, image files) are returning a full error document to the client (26kb) which seems like a bad idea.

Is there a way I can pick up that express.static has caused the error?

I thought about doing something like:

```
if (req.path.indexOf("/images") === 0){
    res.send('Not found');
} else {
    res.render('views/error');
}
```

But I'm looking for something like:

```
if (req.errorFromStatic){
    res.send('Not found');
} else {
    res.render('views/error');
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you find another solution?

Comment: @l2ysho Partially, a messy work around, I enabled fallthrough which gave ENOENT errors which I check in the error trapping and send an empty 404 response, working but still not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs for express static](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static)

There is an `fallthrough` option which will call `next()` for non existing files so your error handler block will reached.

```
app.use("/public", express.static("/static", {fallthrough: false}));
```

In your case

```
['/images','/packages','/scripts','/stylesheets'].forEach(p => {
  app.use(p, express.static(siteSettings.publicFolder + p, {fallthrough: false}));
});
```

Additionally write an own middleware. Put it above your error handler:

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if(['/images', '/packages', '/scripts', '/stylesheets'].includes(req.path)) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, siteSettings.publicFolder, req.originalUrl))) {
            res.send('Not found');
        }
    }
    return next();
});
```

Comment: I've tried this option, all it seems to do is change the error hit in the custom handler from `404 - Not found` to `500 - NOENT file not found`. Both methods already hit the custom error block.

Comment: Rechecking the file system seems even worse than my original solution, I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I think if you want to use something like `req.errorFromStatic` only way is custom middleware with a file checking. But maybe you can overload 404 in nginx/apache and on specific route return custom html page with error

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, you can delegate all work to nginx and return your custom page. It is fast and clean solution but you loose an option to log this attempts in express (but you can see what happening in background in nginx error logs).

Example config:

```
server {
   listen                          80;
   server_name                     example.local;
   charset                         utf-8;

   root /path/to/root/folder;

  location / {
           limit_req               zone=ddos burst=30 nodelay;
           proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
           proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
           proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
           proxy_redirect          off;
           proxy_http_version      1.1;

           proxy_intercept_errors  on;
           error_page 404 @errors;

   }

    location @errors {
            # /path/to/root/folder/404.html;
            try_files /404.html =404;
    }
}
```

In this setup you catch all 404 error and returns custom html, so it is good ideal to create 2 location blocks, one for route to static files and other for api (or whatever) and return a custom page only in a static files.